# Convert from signed to unsigned in VHDL properly

Tags: vhdl

I have a signed accumulator that is used as the index to a BROM LUT. Anyways, I have error checking in my code to detect overflow/underflow events. These are absolutely critical as the application is the AGC of an analog RF front end, so underflowing might cause a booming signal to get maximum gain, blowing up our front end parts. Thus, I need to find a way to properly convert from signed to unsigned. For example, here is what I have so far:

```
library ieee;
...
use ieee.numeric_std.all;
...

process (clk)
    variable preSumV   : signed(accumToLut'left downto 0) := (others => '0');
    variable satCheckV : std_logic_vector(2 downto 0) := (others => '0');
begin
    if rising_edge(clk) then
        if reset = '1' then
            preSumV         := (others => '0');
            satCheckV       := (others => '0');
            overflow        <= '0';
            underflow       <= '0';
            accumToLut      <= (others => '0');
            accumToLutValid <= '0';
        else
            accumToLutValid <= mult.resultValid;

            -- accumulate
            if mult.resultValid = '1' then
                -- perform accum
                preSumV   := preSumV + mult.result(mult.result'left downto mult.result'left-accumToLut'length+1);
                satCheckV := accumToLut(accumToLut'left) & mult.result(mult.result'left) & preSumV(preSumV'left);

                -- check for signed OVF/saturation
                -- A,B is pos, sum neg = overflow so set max pos
                if satCheckV = "001" then
                    overflow <= '1';
                    accumToLut(accumToLut'left) <= '0';
                    accumToLut(accumToLut'left-1 downto 0) <= (others => '1');

                -- A,B is neg, sum pos = underflow so set max neg
                elsif satCheckV = "110" then
                    underflow <= '1';
                    accumToLut(accumToLut'left) <= '1';
                    accumToLut(accumToLut'left-1 downto 0) <= (others => '0');

                -- -- no overflow
                else
                    overflow   <= '0';
                    underflow  <= '0';
                    accumToLut <= preSumV;
                    --accumToLut <= preSumV(preSumV'left-1 downto 0);
                end if;
            end if;
        end if;
    end if;
end process;

accumToLutScaled <= accumToLut(accumToLut'left downto accumToLut'left-GainWordLookup'length+1);
index            <= unsigned(accumToLutScaled);
GainWordLookup   <= c_LinToDbLut(to_integer(accumToLutScaled));
```

The issue I am experiencing is the signed to unsigned conversion with the signal `index`. Because this is signed 2's complement, there is no change in the bits. Thus, when I set the accumToLut value to either the max/min signed value, this is not translating to the corresponding max/min unsigned value when I perform `index <= unsigned(accumToLutScaled)`.

To provide an example, assume that `preSumV`, `mult.result`, and `accumToLut` are all 12 bits. When there is an overflow event, accumToLut gets set to `0x7FF` or `0b0111111111111` which is valid. However, when I convert to unsigned, I would like this to be `FFF`, corresponding to the maximum entry in the LUT. Is it best to just add an offset to the `index` assignment, or is there a cleaner way of doing this?

Comment: Your code is simply a type conversion, not a numerical conversion. There is no proper conversion for what you want - you'll either have to write a custom conversion for it or just use unsigned in the first place. It looks like what you really want as the index is (accumToLutScaled + 2**12)

Comment: I see, so to get the desired behavior, I should be performing 2's comp on the result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From @Tricky, adding a fixed offset based on the size of my table, I have fixed this issue:

`index <= unsigned(accumToLutScaled + 2**(accumToLutScaled'length - 1))`

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're looking for absolute value right?  You want to know when the magnitude of the result is too large, but you don't care about sign.  Use the built-in `abs` function to do this.  I believe the result of abs is an unsigned value, but you might have to cast to unsigned.

```
index <= unsigned(abs(accumToLutScaled));
```

Comment: So, I do need a positive value. However, using abs would give me the same value twice without ever reaching the unsigned full-scale value of `0xfff` for a 12 bit number. The reason this is a concern is that I have a logrithmic LUT for our variable gain amp attn/gain settings. Thus, I need to traverse the whole table. I think the best solution is just changing the offset so that `MAX_NEG` maps to zero per @Tricky

Comment: `abs` is an unary operator (like `not`), but no function. Using parenthesis around the argument of an unary operator is possible, but nut needed. `index <= unsigned(abs accumToLutScaled);`